# Уменьшить размер картинок на лету

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть сайт на Bitrix-е, у него в галерейке выводятся картинки там их мильён штук и все они огроменного размера, примерно по 1000px, так вот в галерейке они уменьшаются стилями , но при нажатии на них открывается полноразмерная картинка. Сам компонент:photogallery.detail.list.ex
файл action.php

```
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
$this->IncludeComponentLang("action.php");

$photo_list_action = $_REQUEST["photo_list_action"];
if (isset($photo_list_action) && $photo_list_action != "")
{
    $APPLICATION->ShowAjaxHead();
    $UCID = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9\_]+/is" , "", $_REQUEST["UCID"]);
    ?><script>
    if (!window.BX && top.BX){BX = top.BX;}
    window.bxph_action_url_<?= $UCID?> = '<?= CUtil::JSEscape(CHTTP::urlDeleteParams(htmlspecialcharsback(POST_FORM_ACTION_URI), array("view_mode", "sessid", "uploader_redirect", "photo_list_action", "pio", "ELEMENT_ID", "UCID"), true));?>';
    <?
    if (!check_bitrix_sessid()){?>window.bxph_error = '<?= GetMessage("IBLOCK_WRONG_SESSION")?>';<?die('</'.'script>');}?>
    </script>
    <?
    if ($photo_list_action == 'load_comments' && $arParams["USE_COMMENTS"] == "Y" && $arParams["PERMISSION"] >= "R")
    {
        $this->InitComponentTemplate("", false, "");
        $arCommentsParams = Array(
            "POPUP_MODE" => "Y",
            "ACTION_URL" => $arParams["ACTION_URL"].(mb_strpos($arParams["ACTION_URL"], "?") === false ? "?" : "&")."photo_list_action=load_comments",
            "IBLOCK_TYPE" => $arParams["IBLOCK_TYPE"],
            "IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams["IBLOCK_ID"],
            "SECTION_ID" => $arParams["SECTION_ID"],
            "ELEMENT_ID" => intval($_REQUEST["photo_element_id"]),
            "COMMENTS_TYPE" => $arParams["COMMENTS_TYPE"],
            "DETAIL_URL" => $arParams["~DETAIL_URL"],
            "SECTION_URL" => $arParams["~SECTION_URL"],
            "COMMENTS_COUNT" => $arParams["COMMENTS_COUNT"],
            "PATH_TO_SMILE" => $arParams["PATH_TO_SMILE"],
            "IS_SOCNET" => $arParams["IS_SOCNET"],
            "SHOW_RATING" => $arParams["USE_RATING"] == "Y" && $arParams["DISPLAY_AS_RATING"] == "rating_main"? "Y": "N",
            "RATING_TYPE" => $arParams["RATING_MAIN_TYPE"],
            "CACHE_TYPE" => "N",
            "CACHE_TIME" => 0,
            "PATH_TO_USER" => $arParams["PATH_TO_USER"],
            "FETCH_USER_ALIAS" => preg_match("/#user_alias#/i".BX_UTF_PCRE_MODIFIER, $arParams["PATH_TO_USER"])
        );

        $arCommentsParams["COMMENTS_TYPE"] = (mb_strtolower($arParams["COMMENTS_TYPE"]) == "forum" ? "forum" : "blog");

        if ($arCommentsParams["COMMENTS_TYPE"] == "blog")
        {
            $arCommentsParams["COMMENTS_TYPE"] = "blog";
            $arCommentsParams["BLOG_URL"] = $arParams["BLOG_URL"];
            $arCommentsParams["PATH_TO_BLOG"] = $arParams["PATH_TO_BLOG"];
        }
        else
        {
            $arCommentsParams["FORUM_ID"] = $arParams["FORUM_ID"];
            $arCommentsParams["USE_CAPTCHA"] = $arParams["USE_CAPTCHA"];
            $arCommentsParams["URL_TEMPLATES_READ"] = $arParams["URL_TEMPLATES_READ"];
            $arCommentsParams["URL_TEMPLATES_PROFILE_VIEW"] = $arParams["URL_TEMPLATES_PROFILE_VIEW"];
            //$arCommentsParams["POST_FIRST_MESSAGE"] = $arParams["POST_FIRST_MESSAGE"];
            //$arCommentsParams["PREORDER"] = ($arParams["PREORDER"] != "N" ? "Y" : "N");
            $arCommentsParams["POST_FIRST_MESSAGE"] = $arParams["POST_FIRST_MESSAGE"] == "N" ? "N" : "Y";
            $arCommentsParams["PREORDER"] = "N";
            $arCommentsParams["SHOW_LINK_TO_FORUM"] = "N";
        }

        if ($arCommentsParams["IS_SOCNET"] == "Y" || !empty($arParams["USER_ALIAS"]))
            $arCommentsParams["USER_ALIAS"] = $arParams["USER_ALIAS"];

        $arCommentsParams["NAME_TEMPLATE"] = $arParams["NAME_TEMPLATE"];

        $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
            "bitrix:photogallery.detail.comment",
            "",
            $arCommentsParams,
            $this,
            array("HIDE_ICONS" => "Y")
        );
    }
    elseif($photo_list_action == 'save_sort_order' && $arParams["PERMISSION"] >= "U")
    {
        CUtil::JSPostUnEscape();
        if (is_array($_REQUEST['pio']))
        {
            CModule::IncludeModule("iblock");
            $bs = new CIBlockElement;
            foreach ($_REQUEST['pio'] as $id => $sort)
            {
                if (intval($id) > 0 && intval($sort) >= 0)
                    $bs->Update(intval($id), array("SORT" => intval($sort)),false,false);
            }

            PClearComponentCacheEx($arParams["IBLOCK_ID"], array(0, $arParams["SECTION_ID"]));
        }
    }
    elseif($photo_list_action == 'save_description' && $arParams["PERMISSION"] >= "U")
    {
        CUtil::JSPostUnEscape();
        CModule::IncludeModule("iblock");
        $arFields = Array("MODIFIED_BY" => $USER->GetID());

        $arFields["PREVIEW_TEXT"] = $_REQUEST["description"];
        $arFields["DETAIL_TEXT"] = $_REQUEST["description"];
        $arFields["DETAIL_TEXT_TYPE"] = "text";
        $arFields["PREVIEW_TEXT_TYPE"] = "text";
        $arFields["IBLOCK_SECTION_ID"] = $arParams["SECTION_ID"];

        $bs = new CIBlockElement;
        $ID = $bs->Update($arParams["ELEMENT_ID"], $arFields);

        if ($ID <= 0)
        {
            ?>
            <script>
                window.bxph_error = '<?= GetMessage("SAVE_DESC_ERROR").": ".$bs->LAST_ERROR?>';
            </script>
            <?
        }
        else
        {
            PClearComponentCacheEx($arParams["IBLOCK_ID"], array(0, $arParams["SECTION_ID"]));
        }
    }
    elseif($photo_list_action == 'activate' && $arParams["PERMISSION"] >= "X")
    {
        CUtil::JSPostUnEscape();
        CModule::IncludeModule("iblock");
        $bs = new CIBlockElement;
        $ID = $bs->Update($arParams["ELEMENT_ID"], Array("MODIFIED_BY" => $USER->GetID(), "ACTIVE" => "Y"));
        if ($ID <= 0)
        {
            ?><script>window.bxph_error = '<?= $bs->LAST_ERROR?>';</script><?
        }
        else
        {
            PClearComponentCacheEx($arParams["IBLOCK_ID"], array(0, $arParams["SECTION_ID"]));
        }
    }
    elseif($photo_list_action == 'rotate' && $_REQUEST['angle'] > 0 && $arParams["PERMISSION"] >= "U")
    {
        CUtil::JSPostUnEscape();
        CModule::IncludeModule("iblock");
        $arFilter = array(
            "IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams["IBLOCK_ID"],
            "SECTION_ID" => $arParams["SECTION_ID"],
            "ID" => $arParams["ELEMENT_ID"],
            "CHECK_PERMISSIONS" => "Y"
        );

        // TODO: add pictures sights to select $arParams["PICTURES_SIGHT"]
        $arSelect = array(
            "DETAIL_PICTURE",
            "PREVIEW_PICTURE",
            "PROPERTY_REAL_PICTURE"
        );

        $angle = intval($_REQUEST['angle']);
        $db_res = CIBlockElement::GetList(array(), $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);

        if ($arRes = $db_res->Fetch())
        {
            // Preview
            if ($arRes["PREVIEW_PICTURE"] > 0)
            {
                $arImg = CFile::MakeFileArray($arRes["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]);
                CFile::ImageRotate($arImg['tmp_name'], $angle);
                $arFields["PREVIEW_PICTURE"] = CFile::MakeFileArray($arImg['tmp_name']);
            }

            // Detail
            if ($arRes["DETAIL_PICTURE"] > 0)
            {
                $arImg = CFile::MakeFileArray($arRes["DETAIL_PICTURE"]);
                CFile::ImageRotate($arImg['tmp_name'], $angle);
                $arFields["DETAIL_PICTURE"] = CFile::MakeFileArray($arImg['tmp_name']);
            }

            // Real
            if ($arRes["PROPERTY_REAL_PICTURE_VALUE"] > 0)
            {
                $arImg = CFile::MakeFileArray($arRes["PROPERTY_REAL_PICTURE_VALUE"]);
                CFile::ImageRotate($arImg['tmp_name'], $angle);
                CIBlockElement::SetPropertyValues($arParams["ELEMENT_ID"], $arParams["IBLOCK_ID"],
                    array(
                        "REAL_PICTURE" => CFile::MakeFileArray($arImg['tmp_name'])
                    ),
                    "REAL_PICTURE"
                );
            }

            $bs = new CIBlockElement;
            if ($res = $bs->Update($arParams["ELEMENT_ID"], $arFields))
            {
                $db_res = CIBlockElement::GetList(array(), $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);

                if ($arRes1 = $db_res->Fetch())
                {
                    $w = 0;
                    $h = 0;
                    $src = '';
                    $thumb_src = '';
                    if ($arRes1["PREVIEW_PICTURE"] > 0)
                    {
                        $file = CFile::GetFileArray($arRes1["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]);
                        $thumb_src = $file['SRC'];
                    }

                    if ($arRes1["PROPERTY_REAL_PICTURE_VALUE"] > 0)
                        $file = CFile::GetFileArray($arRes1["PROPERTY_REAL_PICTURE_VALUE"]);
                    elseif ($arRes1["DETAIL_PICTURE"] > 0)
                        $file = CFile::GetFileArray($arRes1["DETAIL_PICTURE"]);

                    $src = $file['SRC'];
                    $w = $file['WIDTH'];
                    $h = $file['HEIGHT'];

                    ?><script>
                    window.bxphres = {
                        Item: {
                            id: <?= $arParams['ELEMENT_ID']?>,
                            src: '<?= CUtil::JSEscape($file['SRC'])?>',
                            w: parseInt('<?= CUtil::JSEscape($file['WIDTH'])?>'),
                            h: parseInt('<?= CUtil::JSEscape($file['HEIGHT'])?>')
                        }
                    };
                    </script><?

                    PClearComponentCacheEx($arParams["IBLOCK_ID"], array(0, $arParams["SECTION_ID"]));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ?><script>
                window.bxph_error = '<?= GetMessage("ROTATE_ERROR").": ".$bs->LAST_ERROR?>';
                </script><?
            }
        }
    }
    elseif($photo_list_action == 'delete' && $arParams["PERMISSION"] >= "U")
    {
        CUtil::JSPostUnEscape();
        CModule::IncludeModule("iblock");
        @set_time_limit(0);
        $APPLICATION->ResetException();
        $res = CIBlockElement::Delete($arParams["ELEMENT_ID"]);

        if ($res)
        {
            $arEventFields = array(
                "ID" => $arParams["ELEMENT_ID"],
                "IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams["IBLOCK_ID"],
                "SECTION_ID" => $arParams["SECTION_ID"]
            );
            foreach(GetModuleEvents("photogallery", "OnAfterPhotoDrop", true) as $arEvent)
                ExecuteModuleEventEx($arEvent, array($arEventFields, $arParams));
            PClearComponentCacheEx($arParams["IBLOCK_ID"], array(0, $arParams["SECTION_ID"]));
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
            <script>
                window.bxph_error = '<?= GetMessage("DEL_ITEM_ERROR").($ex = $APPLICATION->GetException() ? ': '.$ex->GetString() : '')?>';
            </script>
            <?
        }
    }
    elseif($photo_list_action == 'edit' && $arParams["PERMISSION"] >= "U")
    {
        CUtil::JSPostUnEscape();
        CModule::IncludeModule("iblock");
        if (intval($_REQUEST["SECTION_ID"]) > 0)
            $arParams["SECTION_ID"] = intval($_REQUEST["SECTION_ID"]);
        if (!$arParams["USER_ALIAS"] && isset($_REQUEST["USER_ALIAS"]))
            $arParams["USER_ALIAS"] = $_REQUEST["USER_ALIAS"];

        // Don't delete <!--BX_PHOTO_EDIT_RES-->, <!--BX_PHOTO_EDIT_RES_END--> comments - they are used in js to catch html content
        ?><!--BX_PHOTO_EDIT_RES--><?
        $APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
            "bitrix:photogallery.detail.edit",
            "",
            Array(
                "IBLOCK_TYPE" => $arParams["IBLOCK_TYPE"],
                "IBLOCK_ID" => $arParams["IBLOCK_ID"],
                "USER_ALIAS" => $arParams["USER_ALIAS"],
                "PERMISSION" => $arParams["PERMISSION"],
                "SECTION_ID" => $arParams["SECTION_ID"],
                "SECTION_CODE" => $arParams["SECTION_CODE"],
                "ELEMENT_ID" => $arParams["ELEMENT_ID"],
                "BEHAVIOUR" => $arParams["BEHAVIOUR"],
                "ACTION" => "EDIT",
                "GALLERY_URL" => $arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["gallery"],
                "DETAIL_URL" => $arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["detail"],
                "SECTION_URL" => $arResult["URL_TEMPLATES"]["section"],
                "DATE_TIME_FORMAT" => $arParams["DATE_TIME_FORMAT_DETAIL"],
                "SHOW_TAGS" =>  $arParams["SHOW_TAGS"],
                "GALLERY_SIZE" => $arParams["GALLERY_SIZE"],
                "SET_STATUS_404" => $arParams["SET_STATUS_404"],
                "CACHE_TYPE" => $arParams["CACHE_TYPE"],
                "CACHE_TIME" => $arParams["CACHE_TIME"],
                "DISPLAY_PANEL" => $arParams["DISPLAY_PANEL"],
                "SET_TITLE" => "N",
                "ADD_CHAIN_ITEM" => "N",
                "SHOW_PUBLIC" => "N",
                "SHOW_APPROVE" => "N",
                "SHOW_TITLE" => "N",
                "SEARCH_URL" => $arParams["SEARCH_URL"],
                "~RESTART_BUFFER" => false
            ),
            $component
        );
        ?><!--BX_PHOTO_EDIT_RES_END--><?
    }
    die();
}
?>
```

Шаблон компонента

```
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();
if (empty($arResult["ELEMENTS_LIST"]))
    return true;

if (!$this->__component->__parent || mb_strpos($this->__component->__parent->__name, "photogallery") === false)
{
    $GLOBALS['APPLICATION']->SetAdditionalCSS('/bitrix/components/bitrix/photogallery/templates/.default/style.css');
    $GLOBALS['APPLICATION']->SetAdditionalCSS('/bitrix/components/bitrix/photogallery/templates/.default/themes/gray/style.css');
}

// Javascript for iblock.vote component which used for rating
// file script1.js was special renamed from script.js for prevent auto-including this file to the body of the ajax requests
if ($arParams["USE_RATING"] == "Y" && $arParams["DISPLAY_AS_RATING"] != "rating_main")
    $GLOBALS['APPLICATION']->AddHeadScript('/bitrix/components/bitrix/iblock.vote/templates/ajax_photo/script1.js');

CJSCore::Init(array('window', 'ajax', 'tooltip', 'popup'));

/********************************************************************
                Input params
********************************************************************/
// PICTURE
$temp = array("STRING" => preg_replace("/[^0-9]/is", "/", $arParams["THUMBNAIL_SIZE"]));
list($temp["WIDTH"], $temp["HEIGHT"]) = explode("/", $temp["STRING"]);
$arParams["THUMBNAIL_SIZE"] = (intval($temp["WIDTH"]) > 0 ? intval($temp["WIDTH"]) : 120);

if ($arParams["PICTURES_SIGHT"] != "standart" && intval($arParams["PICTURES"][$arParams["PICTURES_SIGHT"]]["size"]) > 0)
    $arParams["THUMBNAIL_SIZE"] = $arParams["PICTURES"][$arParams["PICTURES_SIGHT"]]["size"];

$arParams["ID"] = md5(serialize(array("default", $arParams["FILTER"], $arParams["SORTING"])));
$arParams["SHOW_RATING"] = ($arParams["SHOW_RATING"] == "N" ? "N" : "Y");
$arParams["SHOW_SHOWS"] = ($arParams["SHOW_SHOWS"] == "N" ? "N" : "Y");
$arParams["SHOW_COMMENTS"] = ($arParams["SHOW_COMMENTS"] == "N" ? "N" : "Y");
$arParams["COMMENTS_TYPE"] = (mb_strtolower($arParams["COMMENTS_TYPE"]) == "blog" ? "blog" : "forum");
$arParams["SHOW_DATETIME"] = ($arParams["SHOW_DATETIME"] == "Y" ? "Y" : "N");
$arParams["SHOW_DESCRIPTION"] = ($arParams["SHOW_DESCRIPTION"] == "Y" ? "Y" : "N");

// PAGE
$arParams["SHOW_PAGE_NAVIGATION"] = (in_array($arParams["SHOW_PAGE_NAVIGATION"], array("none", "top", "bottom", "both")) ?
        $arParams["SHOW_PAGE_NAVIGATION"] : "bottom");
$arParams["NEW_DATE_TIME_FORMAT"] = trim(!empty($arParams["NEW_DATE_TIME_FORMAT"]) ? $arParams["NEW_DATE_TIME_FORMAT"] :
    $DB->DateFormatToPHP(CSite::GetDateFormat("SHORT")));

$arParams["GROUP_DATE"] = ($arParams["GROUP_DATE"] == "Y" ? "Y" : "N");
/********************************************************************
                Input params
********************************************************************/

$ucid = CUtil::JSEscape($arParams["~UNIQUE_COMPONENT_ID"]);

$current_date = "";
?>



<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="pr_our_work">         
            <div class="pr_our_work_content">
                <ul class="pr_our_work_area">
                    <?/* Used to show 'More photos' in js*/
                    if($_REQUEST['get_elements_html']){ob_start();}?>

                    <?
                    foreach ($arResult["ELEMENTS_LIST"] as $key => $arItem)
                    {

                        $arItem["TITLE"] = htmlspecialcharsEx($arItem["~PREVIEW_TEXT"]);
                        $alt = $arItem["TITLE"];
                        if ($alt === '')
                            $alt = $arItem["NAME"];

                        if ($arParams['MODERATION'] == 'Y' && $arParams["PERMISSION"] >= "W")
                        {
                            $bNotActive = $arItem["ACTIVE"] != "Y";
                            $arItem["TITLE"] .= '['.GetMessage("P_NOT_MODERATED").']';
                        }

                        if ($arParams["DRAG_SORT"] == "Y")
                            $arItem["TITLE"] .= " - ".GetMessage("START_DRAG_TO_SORT");
                        $arItem["TITLE"] = trim($arItem["TITLE"], " -");

                        $src = $arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["SRC"];
                        $w = intval($arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["WIDTH"]);
                        $h = intval($arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["HEIGHT"]);
                        if (!$w || !$h)
                            continue;
                        $r = $w / $h;

                        if ($r > 1)
                        {
                            $item_w = 'width: '.($arParams['THUMBNAIL_SIZE'] * $r).'px;';
                            $item_h = 'height: '.$arParams['THUMBNAIL_SIZE']."px;";
                            $item_left = 'left: '.round(($arParams['THUMBNAIL_SIZE'] - $arParams['THUMBNAIL_SIZE'] * $r /*width*/) / 2).'px;';
                            $item_top = '';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $item_w = 'width: '.$arParams['THUMBNAIL_SIZE'].'px;';
                            $item_h = 'height: '.round($arParams['THUMBNAIL_SIZE'] / $r).'px;';
                            $item_top = 'top: '.round(($arParams['THUMBNAIL_SIZE'] - $arParams['THUMBNAIL_SIZE'] / $r /*height*/) / 2).'px;';
                            $item_left = '';
                        }
                    ?>
                    
                        <li class="portfolio_item"><a href="<?= $src?>" data-fancybox="gallery"><div><img src="<?= $src?>" style="<?= $item_w?> <?= $item_h?> <?= $item_left?> <?= $item_top?>;"></div></a></li> 
                    
                    <?
                    };

                    if($_REQUEST['get_elements_html']){$elementsHTML = ob_get_clean();}
                    ?>
                </ul>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .pr_our_work_bg{}
    .pr_our_work{margin: 0 auto;width: 100%;}
    .pr_our_work_content{}
    ul.pr_our_work_area{list-style: none;    padding: 0;    margin: 0;    overflow: hidden;    padding-bottom: 0px;}
    ul.pr_our_work_area li{text-align: center;    margin-bottom: 50px;}
    ul.pr_our_work_area li a{display: block;transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;    width: 316px;    height: 316px;    margin: 0 auto;     border: 2px solid #eaeaea;border-radius: 25px; overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;}
    ul.pr_our_work_area li a div {    width: 292px;
    height: 292px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;}
    ul.pr_our_work_area li a img{width: 292px;
    height: 292px;
    /* border-radius: 20px; */
    position: absolute;
    /* border: none; */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    max-height: none !important;
    max-width: none !important;}
    ul.pr_our_work_area li a:hover {border: 2px solid #fda12b;}

.pr_our_work_more_btn {    width: 250px;    margin: 50px auto 0;    padding-bottom: 50px;}
    .pr_our_work_more_btn a{transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;    border: 1px solid #fda12b;    border-radius: 25px;    text-align: center;    display: block;    line-height: 48px;    margin: 0 auto;    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #FDD32B, #FDA12B);    color: #fff;    height: 50px;    box-shadow: 0 3px 8px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.92);margin-top: 10px;}
    .pr_our_work_more_btn a:hover{opacity:0.8}

@media (min-width:769px){
    .pr_our_work_bg{}
    .pr_our_work{margin: 0 auto;}
    .pr_our_work_content{}
    ul.pr_our_work_area{list-style: none;    padding: 0;    margin: 0;    overflow: hidden;    padding-bottom: 0px;height: auto;}
    ul.pr_our_work_area li{width: 50%;    float: left;    text-align: center;    margin-bottom: 50px;}
    ul.pr_our_work_area li a{display: block;transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;    width: 316px;    height: 316px;    margin: 0 auto;    border: 2px solid #eaeaea;}
    ul.pr_our_work_area li a img{width: 292px;height: 292px;}
    ul.pr_our_work_area li a:hover {border: 2px solid #fda12b;}
    
}

@media (min-width:1197px){
    .pr_our_work_bg{}
    .pr_our_work{width: 1110px;margin: 0 auto;}
    .pr_our_work_content{}
    ul.pr_our_work_area{list-style: none;    padding: 0;    margin: 0;    overflow: hidden;    padding-bottom: 0px;}
    ul.pr_our_work_area li{width: 33.3333%;    float: left;    text-align: center;    margin-bottom: 50px;}
    ul.pr_our_work_area li a{display: block;transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;    width: 316px;    height: 316px;    margin: 0 auto;   border: 2px solid #eaeaea;}
    ul.pr_our_work_area li a img{width: 292px;height: 292px;}
    ul.pr_our_work_area li a:hover {border: 2px solid #fda12b;}
}

</style>
```

Файл result_modifier.php

```
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();

$arParams1 = array(
    "MAX_VOTE" => intval($arParams["MAX_VOTE"])<=0? 5: intval($arParams["MAX_VOTE"]),
    "VOTE_NAMES" => is_array($arParams["VOTE_NAMES"])? $arParams["VOTE_NAMES"]: array(),
    "DISPLAY_AS_RATING" => $arParams["DISPLAY_AS_RATING"]);
$arResult["VOTE_NAMES"] = array();
foreach($arParams1["VOTE_NAMES"] as $k=>$v)
{
    if($v <> '')
        $arResult["VOTE_NAMES"][]=htmlspecialcharsbx($v);
    if(count($arResult["VOTE_NAMES"])>=$arParams1["MAX_VOTE"])
        break;
}
?>
```

Читал офф. документацию по этому вопросу, вообще ничего не понял, не осознал, пытался на лету ужимать картинки -> папка с урезанными картинками создалась, а как вытащить их не могу.

Comment: Пробую вот так в шаблоне компонента 
      $renderImage = CFile::ResizeImageGet($arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"], Array("width" => НОВАЯ_ШИРИНА, "height" => НОВАЯ_ВЫСОТА), BX_RESIZE_IMAGE_EXACT, false);

Но $renderImage пустая

Comment: А самое интересное что после удаления папки resize_cache - она больше не создается

Answer (score 0):

Опять как говориться столкнулся с дичью. $arItem["PREVIEW_PICTURE"] был разбит на два массива зачем то и пересобран. В нем не было ID фотографии и метод просто не находил фотографию(а находит он находит только по ID или надо очень там сильно измудряться). Отвардампил весь массив $arItem, нашел там $arItem["~PREVIEW_PICTURE"] с ID фото и в параметр метода вставил вот так :

$renderImage = CFile::ResizeImageGet($arItem["~PREVIEW_PICTURE"], Array("width" => НОВАЯ_ШИРИНА, "height" => НОВАЯ_ВЫСОТА), BX_RESIZE_IMAGE_EXACT, false);

Создался каталог resize_cache и из него уже достаем фото $renderImage['src'] по пути из этой папки. Все заработало